# Return loss of antenna

Tags: antenna

I was borrowing a Field Fox VNA to look at some antennas and was trying to verify what I was seeing with a known antenna.

What I am confused about is the return loss graph of this antenna from mouser
https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/398/TD_10_5113-1508769.pdf
[image]
On the Field Fox VNA I am seeing this, which is totally different to the graph in the datasheet.

[image]

Is it possible the Antenna Datasheet is nonsense or the VNA is broken?

Interestingly I have a 2.4ghz antenna that doesn't provide a return loss chart, but I do see a large dip at around 2.4ghz in the return loss, as I would expect, as in this picture, which suggest the instrument is ok?

[image]

Comment: Is it calibrated to your feed point at antenna?

Comment: Hi yes. There is an n-type to sma adapter between the VNA and the antenna, and I've done the calibration.

Comment: Looks like it barely meets spec <-10 dB

Comment: Test it with a 50 ohm resistor.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet is quite vague about the test conditions. Your test condition is undoubtedly different. Details of connections and what's in the vicinity matter. Unless you take steps to isolate the VNA from RF reflected back onto it in common mode, the VNA is part of the antenna. Your result is not "out of family" with the plots of various tests.